# Relacionar um input do usuário com um ponteiro de uma classe

Tags: c++, classes, ponteiro

Gostaria de relacionar o ponteiro da classe correspondendo ao input do usuário e apresentar na tela os atributos relacionados a esse objeto.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classes.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sLeitor,sLivro,*pLivro;
    int iLivro;
    cout << "Digite o numero do livro que deseja ler: ";
    cin >> iLivro;
    sLivro = "livro" + to_string(iLivro);  // tentei converter int para string para ponteiro

    pLivro << sLivro; 
    cin.ignore();

    cout << "Digite seu nome: ";
    getline(cin,sLeitor);
    cout << endl;

    Livros *livro1 = new Livros("Pesquisa Operacional","Wagner",851,sLeitor);
    Livros *livro2 = new Livros("Probabilidade e Estatistica","Spiegel",517,sLeitor);
    Livros *livro3 = new Livros("Um Curso de Calculo - Volume 1","Guidorizzi",580,sLeitor);

    pLivro->consultar();

    return 0;
}
```

```
// A classe está assim, tem alguns recursos a mais:

#ifndef CLASSES_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASSES_H_INCLUDED

using namespace std;

class Livros{
public:
    Livros (string sNome, string sAutor, int iQdtPaginas, string sLeitor);
    ~Livros();
    void setNome(string sNome);
    string getLeitor();
    string getNome();
    void consultar();

private:
    string sNome;
    string sAutor;
    int iQtdPaginas=0;
    string sLeitor;
};

Livros::Livros(string sNome, string sAutor, int iQtdPaginas, string sLeitor){
    this->sNome=sNome;
    this->sAutor=sAutor;
    this->iQtdPaginas=iQtdPaginas;
    this->sLeitor=sLeitor;
}

void Livros::setNome(string sNome){
    this->sNome=sNome;
}

string Livros::getLeitor(){
    return this->sLeitor;
}

string Livros::getNome(){
    return this->sNome;
}

Livros::~Livros(){
    cout << "Objeto destruido!" << endl;
}

void Livros::consultar(){
    cout << "Nome do livro: " << this->sNome << endl;
    cout << "Nome do autor: " << this->sAutor << endl;
    cout << "Quantidade de paginas: " << this->iQtdPaginas << endl;
    cout << "Leitor(a): " << this->sLeitor << endl;
    cout << endl;
}

#endif // CLASSES_H_INCLUDED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha sugestão para vc é utilizar um vector como contêiner dos livros e utilizar os indexadores da estrutura como opções em um menu de seleção.

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include "classes.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sLeitor;
    cout << "Digite seu nome: ";
    getline(cin,sLeitor);
    cout << endl;

    std::vector<Livros> biblioteca {
        Livros("Pesquisa Operacional","Wagner",851,sLeitor),
        Livros("Probabilidade e Estatistica","Spiegel",517,sLeitor),
        Livros("Um Curso de Calculo - Volume 1","Guidorizzi",580,sLeitor)
    };

    int index = 0;
    cout << "Livros Disponíveis\n";
    for(auto livro : biblioteca) {
        std::cout << index++ << "->\t" << livro.getNome() << "\n";
    }
    cout << "Digite o numero do livro que deseja ler: ";
    int iLivro; cin >> iLivro;

    if(iLivro < biblioteca.size())
        biblioteca.at(iLivro).consultar();

    return 0;
}
```

Caso vc precise de alocação dinâmica será necessário ajustar o vector para que ele acomode os ponteiros, mas nessa implementação nunca será necessário expor os ponteiros para o usuário da interface.

Answer (score 0):

Dessa maneira meu problema foi resolvido

```
#include <iostream>
#include "classes.h"
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sLeitor;
    cout << "Digite seu nome: ";
    getline(cin,sLeitor);

    vector <Livros> biblioteca {
        Livros("Um Curso de Calculo - Volume 1","Guidorizzi",580,sLeitor),
        Livros("Os elementos","Euclides",600,sLeitor),
        Livros("Principia","Newton",328,sLeitor),
        Livros("Introduction to Quantum Mechanics","Griffiths",508,sLeitor),
        Livros("Licoes de Fisica","Feynman",1604,sLeitor)
    };

    int iLivro;
    cout << "Digite o numero do livro que deseja ler: ";
    cin >> iLivro;
    cout << endl;

    if(iLivro <= biblioteca.size()){
        biblioteca.at(iLivro-1).consultar();
    }else{
        cout << "A biblioteca nao possui esse livro" << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```